# template won't render from model object after sorting

Tags: ember.js, promise

I am sorting an array of objects queried from Ember-Data by 'type'-key before returning them in the [`model()`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_model)-method of an `Ember.Route` to be rendered.

*app/routes/test.js*

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    let obj = Ember.Object.create({a: [], b: [], c: []});
    this.get('store').findAll('obj').then(function(unsorted){
      unsorted.forEach(function(item) {// sort per type
        obj.get(item.get('type')).addObject(item);
      });
      return obj;
    });
  }
});
```

The array returned by (the promise of) the Ember-Data query looks like this (all objects have Ember internal properties)

```
[
  {
    _id: '1',
    type: 'a',
    properties: {...}
  },
  {
    ...
  },
  {
    _id: '15',
    type: 'b',
    properties: {...}
  }
]
```

And the new object with objects sorted by "type"-key looks like this

```
{
  a: [{
      _id: '1',
      type: 'a',
      properties: {...}
    },
    ...
  ],
  b: [
    ... ,
    {
      _id: '15',
      type: 'b',
      properties: {...}
    },
  c: [...]
};
```

*app/routes/test.hbs*

```
<h2>Test</h2>
<h3>Type a</h3>
{{#each model.a as |source|}}
  <div>
    {{source.properties.prop1}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

The template doesn't render the part that loops over the array, nor does the Ember-inspector plugin list the `Model` property under "Own properties" of the route (right panel in "View tree"-mode).

However, when returning a POJO (literally pasting object with array's by key in code) everything behaves as expected.
I suspect this has something to do with the internal (Ember-)properties of the objects returned by Ember-data (I have read about the owner of an object etc.) but I can't seem to figure this out ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of @Pavol gets to the basic problem, however `return this.store...then(...)` **will work** because this is how promises work. Read [the documentation](https://promisesaplus.com).

So this will work:

```
model() {
  let obj = Ember.Object.create({a: [], b: [], c: []});
  return this.get('store').findAll('obj').then(function(unsorted){
    unsorted.forEach(function(item) {// sort per type
      obj.get(item.get('type')).addObject(item);
    });
    return obj;
  });
}
```

`.then(onFulfilled)` returns a new promise, that will resolve with the return value of the `onFulfilled`-callback. Creating a new promise with `new Promise(...)` is always totally useless if you already have promises and only for interoperability with callback-style code.

Comment: With @Pavol 's answer I already realized that the problem was more about my understanding of promises in general than my knowledge of the ember framework, thanks all for the input!

Answer (score -1):

You are missing return statement in your `model()` hook:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    let obj = Ember.Object.create({a: [], b: [], c: []});
    this.get('store').findAll('obj').then(function(unsorted){
      unsorted.forEach(function(item) {// sort per type
        obj.get(item.get('type')).addObject(item);
      });
      return obj;
    });
    // no return value before, findAll() returns promise, thus model() returns undefined
  }
});
```

<strike>However, adding `return this.store...` won't solve your situation since you are updating different object after your promise is solved (the `then()` function).
I would recommend wrapping it in a promise and resolve it passing a modified object based on your sorting logic.</strike> 
Note: I did not consider whether sorting at this stage makes sense and is of 'Ember-way'. Sorting usually happens via computed properties on controller/component level.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {

    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve)=>{
       let obj = Ember.Object.create({a: [], b: [], c: []});
       this.get('store').findAll('obj').then(function(unsorted){
        unsorted.forEach(function(item) {// sort per type
          obj.get(item.get('type')).addObject(item);
        });
        resolve(obj);
      });
    });

  }
});
```

Update: Of course `this.store()` returns a valid promise (which I pointed out in the snippet but explained incorrectly later) and so you do not have to wrap it, sorry for the confusement! I haven´t realized that return value of the callback passed to `then()` is automatically internally passed in a promise, although I use promise chaining and this on a daily basis, too. Shame on me! Thx @Lux for putting this on a right way.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try :-) 
On the subject of this not being the 'Ember-way': I have been asking myself the same question, but I'm new to Ember and I'm not sure what the best way to handle this is ... I'd love to have some advice about this

Comment: I highly recommend to start with EmberJS guidelines (CP begin [here](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/object-model/computed-properties/)). This is a link to the [respective CP API](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html). There are several examples that will show you the right way.

Comment: First its totally valid and emberish to process the model in the `model()` hook, next its your statement about how promises work is wrong.

Comment: I meant it well but explained it terribly, thanks for fixing me @Lux